# Hyper-V Core - how to connect to/manage VMs?

Tags: hyper-v, remote-desktop

Very basic question unanswered from Googling:

I've installed Hyper-V **Core**, configured the network, created a new VM and set a DVD drive with an ISO of a Windows XP installation disc assigned to it. The VM has started.

What software do I use and what steps do I take to now view and interact with the VM - an equivalent of vSphere Client? I will need to do it from a remote machine, preferably running Windows 7.

I've read a lot about remote *management* of the Core instance, but that is not what I am aiming for.

Comment: there is a way now... visit my blog at stephanco.blogspot.com/2013/06/building-hyper-v-vhost-without-buying.html, it is not that pretty but it works. All freeware and ready to rock and roll, my app/scripts will replace vmconnect.exe and hyper-v manager.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remote Management of the hyper-v core *is* what you're looking for.

It's included in RSAT for the different versions of Windows. Use RSAT on Windows 7 to manage Windows 2008 R2 Hyper-V, and RSAT on Windows 8 to manage Windows 2012 Hyper-V.

Also - you can just use RDP to the Windows XP VM, like you would to any other computer.

Comment: Can I connect an RDP session to the VM while it is installing Windows, i.e. before the OS is properly running?

Comment: You can connect to the console of the VM by using the HYPER-V management tools by installing the RSAT on your management computer, as pauska has stated in the answer.

Comment: Once you've installed the Hyper-V RSAT tools, you can also launch `c:\Program Files\Hyper-V\vmconnect.exe` and connect to a VM console directly without needing to load the Hyper-V manager.